# How to navigate to a different url after deleting an item from a list in sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I have a list webpart view on a page. On edit when I am trying to delete the item, it takes me to the list allaspx page. But I want it to navigate to a different page. When I changed the save button source url then after delete it is taking me to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the source url parameter.

Sample script:

```
window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', 'pageurl?Source=targeturl');
```